# Cast from '(NSNumber) -> NSNumber' to unrelated type '(Any) -> Any' always fails

Tags: objective-c, swift

I convert this Objective-C function:

```
- (NSArray *)grt_map:(id (^)(id))block {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id item, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        id obj = block(item);
        if (obj) {
            [newArray addObject:obj];
        }
    }];
    return newArray;
}
```

...into Swift:

```
public func grt_map(block:((Any) -> Any)) -> NSArray {
    let array = NSMutableArray()
    self.enumerateObjects ({ (item:Any, index:Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>)->Void in
        if (block(item) != nil) {
            array.add(item)
        }
    })
    return array;
}
```

But I get an error:

> Cast from '(NSNumber) -> NSNumber' to unrelated type '(Any) -> Any' always fails

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should be using Swift arrays, not `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Also, your Swift rendition is not doing the same thing as your Objective-C version: You're throwing away the response of the `block`.

Comment: Literal translations from ObjC to Swift are awful in most cases. As already mentioned use native `Array` and instead of `enumerateObjects` use `flatMap()` which can also take a closure. And *snake_cased* method names are uncool anyway ;-)

Comment: But I wonder at which line you're getting this error. It looks like a problem that would arise at the point you call `grt_map`, not within `grt_map`. It looks like you're passing it a closure of `NSNumber` values. Frankly, I'd discourage the use of `Any` (or `AnyObject`), regardless. Either specify the particular type or use a generic. But `Any`/`AnyObject` like this is a bit unswifty.

Comment: With Swift arrays you get that functionality for free with the built-on `map` or `flatMap` methods.

Comment: I'd suggest retiring this `grt_map` entirely, and just use `flatMap`.

Comment: Thanks guy for all support, i had learned so much from this :D

Answer (score 0):

If make extension for nsarray, you should remember it takes objects that can be casted to objc types. 
Change this:

```
public func grt_map(block:((Any) -> Any)) -> NSArray
```

To this:

```
public func grt_map(block:((AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? )) -> NSArray
```

For using Any, extension should be for Array, not NSArray

**update**
Test like this:
    array.grt_map(block: {(item: AnyObject?) in ...}

Comment: I fix it but in if block :if (block(item as AnyObject) != nil) {
                array.add(item)
            } have some notify with this warn "Comparing non-optional value of type 'AnyObject' to nil always returns true" - how to fix it

Comment: o, sorry. id type is nullable, so make `public func grt_map(block:((AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? )) -> NSArray`

Comment: Thank you. but when i test it:
func test_grt_map()
    {
        let list : NSArray = [1, 2, 3]
        var result : NSArray = list;
        result = list.grt_map(block: { (num:NSNumber) in
            return num
        })
        XCTAssertTrue(list.isEqual(to: result as! [Any]));
    }
 this code throw an error "Cannot convert value of type '(NSNumber) -> NSNumber' to expected argument type '(Any) -> Any'"

Comment: @HoangTuan provide test code. I don't know how you use it )))

Comment: Ok, this function i used to add more extension to NSArray, this is my class:
extension NSArray {
    public func grt_map(block:((AnyObject) -> AnyObject?)) -> NSArray {
        let array = NSMutableArray()
        self.enumerateObjects ({ (item:Any, index:Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>)->Void in
            if (block(item as AnyObject) != nil) {
                array.add(item)
            }
        })
        return array;
    }
}

Comment: @HoangTuan ok, for your testing code, it should look like this:  `result = list.grt_map(block: { (num: AnyObject?) in`, because your nsarray items are also NSObjects

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it but it too hard for use so i move to use flatMap()

Comment: @HoangTuan I thought u need custom method. If flatmap is enough for you, it’s better choice

Comment: Thank you, i have some minimal task for this custom method but i did it with flat map and it is quite enough.

Comment: Ah, @Максуд Даудов Do you know how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466923/cgpdfstreamcopydata-get-data-from-cgpdfpage