# CGPDFStreamCopyData get data from CGPDFPage

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get string data from pdf page data stream and i used CGPDFStreamCopyData() to get string data stream but alway it throw error, Any one have some way to workaround or have some suggest for me?

Comment: Workaround for what? You did not show any code! – A [mcve] is needed.

Comment: Oh sorrry, i want to convert this code from objective c to swift but i don't know how:

- (instancetype)initWithStream:(CGPDFStreamRef)stream
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSData *data = (__bridge_transfer NSData*)CGPDFStreamCopyData(stream, nil);
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        _lines = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet];
    }
    return self;
}

Answer (score 0):

Data should be referenced.

```
NSData* data =...
```

Also, check code, where you create your stream

Comment: Do you know how to do this on swift